# How to extract json value in perl

Tags: perl

i am trying to extract the the values which I need 'system1 system2 system3 system4' . I used to extract the content from `$json` output like below. I am getting error `ARRAY(0x210e150)`. Please suggest how to retrieve those values only.

```
$VAR1 = {
          'response' => {
                          'mydocs' => [
                                      {
                                        'host' => 'system1'
                                      },
                                      {
                                        'host' => 'system2'
                                      },
                                      {
                                        'host' => 'system3'
                                      },
                                      {
                                        'host' => 'system4'
                                      }
                                      ],
                                      }

                                   };

use LWP::Simple;              
use JSON;    
use Data::Dumper;               


my $url = "https://localhost/content;

my $json = from_json(get($url));

print Dumper($json); # received above output

print "$json->{'response'}->{'docs'}";

for my $data (@$json) {
    my $result = ref $data->{response} ? $data->{response}->{docs} : $data->{response};
    print "Result is $result\n";
}
```

Comment: The `ARRAY(0x210e150)` is not an error. It's the string representation/address of a data structure.

Comment: The code does not make sense for the output you are showing. There is no array ref in `$json` if that is what you are showing as `$VAR1`. Also you keep referring to a key `docs`, but there is only `mydocs` in your data. If thee output `ARRAY(0x210e150)` is from the `print "$json->{'response'}->{'docs'}` line, then it is pretty much correct, assuming there is a key `docs` (and not `mydocs`), because that contains an array ref with a bunch of hash refs inside, and if you `print` that, it will show the address. You could `Dumper` it like you did above to see something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$json` is a hash reference, not an array reference, so looping over `@$json` won't work. What you need to do is delve down to where the array of hashes starts, and loop over that:

```
for my $host (@{ $json->{response}{mydocs} }){
    print "host: $host->{host}\n";
}
```

...and this:

```
print "$json->{'response'}->{'mydocs'}";
```

...is printing out the memory address of the `mydocs` array reference. What I do above is loop over this array reference extracting each hash reference it contains one at a time, then work on that.